# Converting AngularJS to Angular by simply changing the directive names and changing the structure to suit these directives?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, angular8

I have this block of html with AngularJS directives. I want to convert this to Angular8. In my angular project I made a custom component called `destination`. In my destination ts file called `destination.component.ts` I imported data from a json file and assigned the data to a destinations component `destinations = data;` so the data can be used in `destination.component.html`.

**destination.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from './destinations.json';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-destination',
   templateUrl: './destination.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./destination.component.css']
 })
export class DestinationComponent implements OnInit {

  destinations = data;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(data.bro_intel);
 }

}
```

**destination.component.html**

```
<div class="feature-panel" style="margin-top: 20px;">
 <div class="double-container">
<div class="left">
  <div class="feature-title"> Featured Destinations</div>
  <div class="feature-icon-content">
    <div class="destination-icon-container" ng-repeat="destination in destinations" title="{{destination.label}}" ng-click="select(destination)" ng-if="destination.product_type != 'custom'">
      <div class="destination-count" ng-show="all_dest_map[destination.product_type] > 0">{{all_dest_map[destination.product_type]}}</div>
      <img src="{{icon_url +  destination.icon}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="feature-title">
    Other destinations&nbsp;
    <div style="margin: -20px 0 0 130px;" class="destination-count" ng-show="all_dest_map['custom']>0">{{all_dest_map['custom']}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="feature-others-content">
    <div style="font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 15px;padding: 5px;">
      We can send threat intelligence to any product that allows for file based integration.
      We do not currently support API integrations.
    </div>
    <div class="setup-label" ng-click="select(icon_map['custom'])">
      Set up Custom Destination
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Would converting my AngularJS directives in the html to their Angular8 directive equivalent work?
If yes then what would it look like? If not then how would I go about achieving this?

Note, I'm completely new to Angular and AngularJs.

Comment: You have to know the syntax, but yes, it *could* work. Depends on your business logic & all, but it could. Also, don't expect anyone here to do it for you, instead ask us when you encounter an issue with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes replacing the angularjs directives with its angular equivalent would work. ng-repeat should be changed to *ngFor, ng-if to *ngIf, and ng-click to (click). Your modified template should look like-

```
 <div class="feature-panel" style="margin-top: 20px;">
     <div class="double-container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="feature-title"> Featured Destinations</div>
      <div class="feature-icon-content">
<ng-container  *ngFor="let destination of destinations">
        <div class="destination-icon-container" title="{{destination.label}}" (click)="select(destination)" *ngIf="destination.product_type != 'custom'">
          <div class="destination-count" *ngIf="all_dest_map[destination.product_type] > 0">{{all_dest_map[destination.product_type]}}</div>
          <img src="{{icon_url +  destination.icon}}">
        </div>
</ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="feature-title">
        Other destinations&nbsp;
        <div style="margin: -20px 0 0 130px;" class="destination-count" *ngIf="all_dest_map['custom']>0">{{all_dest_map['custom']}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-others-content">
        <div style="font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 15px;padding: 5px;">
          We can send threat intelligence to any product that allows for file based integration.
          We do not currently support API integrations.
        </div>
        <div class="setup-label" (click)="select(icon_map['custom'])">
          Set up Custom Destination
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```